# Reverse Geolocation not returning correct country name

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, unity-game-engine, reverse-geocoding

I am working in Unity with Google Maps Reverse Geolocation to find the country name of the latitude and longitude that is entered.

I have tested the code by inputting locations from around the world via the Inspector.
Each time, it outputs the name of the country (such as UK, USA, France, Singapore etc).
However, when I input a Russian lat and long, it only returns a number.
This number turns out to be a postals code for the area.

This is the code I'm using:

```
 private string GoogleAPIKey = "MY KEY";

     public string latitude;
     public string longitude;
 private string countryLocation;
 public Text console;

     IEnumerator Start()
    {
         if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser){

             yield break;          
        }
         Input.location.Start();

         int maxWait = 20;

         while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
         {
           yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
             maxWait--;
         }
         if (maxWait < 1)
         {
             yield break;
         }
         if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
         {
                 yield break;
         }
         else
         {

             longitude = Input.location.lastData.longitude.ToString();
             latitude = Input.location.lastData.latitude.ToString();
           console.text += (latitude + " " + longitude);
         }
         Input.location.Stop();

         using (WWW www = new WWW("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" +latitude +","+ longitude   + "&key=" + GoogleAPIKey)){
             yield return www;

             if(www.error == null)
             {
                 var location =  Json.Deserialize(www.text) as Dictionary<string, object>;
                 var locationList = location["results"] as List<object>;
                 var locationListing = locationList[0] as Dictionary<string, object>;
                      countryLocation = locationListing["formatted_address"].ToString().Substring(locationListing["formatted_address"].ToString().LastIndexOf(",")+2);

                   console.text += (" LOCATION IS: " + countryLocation.ToString());
             }else{
                console.text += www.error;
            }
         };

    }
```

I have tired several locations within Russia and it only outputs the number.
I don't know if this happens with other countries but the others I've tried have worked correctly and output the country name.

Comment: Can you provide latitude,longutude value that you tried and that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Parsing the formatted address as a string is not the best approach to get the country name since, as you have discovered, Russian addresses end with postal code. The country name is provided in `address_components` as a separate object.

You want to retrieve `results.address_components[].long_name` where `types` is `[country, political]`.

Here is an abbreviated response showing the country object:

```
{
   "plus_code": {
      "compound_code": "9XMF+9P Yegoryevsk, Moscow Oblast, Russia",
      "global_code": "9G7W9XMF+9P"
   },
   "results": [
      {
         "address_components": [
            {
               "long_name": "Russia",
               "short_name": "RU",
               "types": [
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address": "Unnamed Road, Moskovskaya oblast', Russia, 140301",
       }
   ],
   "status": "OK"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan Wilson This seems to be the way to do it.
Just got to work out how to translate that into C#!